# htaccess using subdomain resource like css,js,images in main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

Let's say, I have a domain example.com and a subdomain test.example.com.  I have hosted all CSS, JavaScript, images in my subdomain (test.example.com).

Now what I want to achieve through the .htaccess file is when I  access .css file from the page in main domain (example.com) ie- index.php like example.com/css/style.css (note that there is no such folder and file in main domain) it should access the resource of sub domain ie- it should be redirected to test.example.com/css/style.css.

Similarly I want to access .js and image files in the same manner. How can I achieve this using htaccess?

Comment: Are they pointing to the same server (and same document root folder) ?

Comment: They are at the same server, but pointing to different root. exmaple.com in public_html and test.example.com in public_html/test